# Keyboard event does not work in Chrome 53

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am using the keyboard event for my dropdown control in angularjs as below code. It is working fine in chrome 49 but it does not work in chrome 53. So i dont know whether this issue is in chrome 53 or the codes which i am using is not valid for this chrome version. So suggest me best solution for this.

Here is my code.

```
element.on("keydown", onKeyDown);

function onKeyDown() {
          var elem=angular.element(element.find('select'));
          var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
          e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,false, false, false, false, 0, null);
         elem.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

//this code before I expands the dropdown in the previous version of chrome

```
  if (document.createEvent) {
            var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            el[0].dispatchEvent(e);
        } else if (element.fireEvent) {
            el[0].fireEvent("onmousedown");
        }
```

now in version 53 does nothing

any ideas?

Comment: Can you show HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e is an untrusted event, since it was made with createEvent(). Starting with Chrome 53, untrusted events do not invoke the default action.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted